# Animating a programmatically added UIView splits the width in half

Tags: ios, swift, jquery-animate, cabasicanimation

I am working on a very basic animation. A green line that's the full width of the main View, 30 pt tall, and animates from the bottom of the screen to the top of the screen.

There's a button that triggers this animation. Before I press the button, the green view is full width. Great! When I press the button to animate it, the views width splits in half when it starts to animate.

Here's what I have:

**Class level**

```
let animatedLineView = UIView()
let lineAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
super.viewDidLoad()
animatedLineView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height - 30, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 30)
animatedLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
self.view.addSubview(animatedLineView)
```

**Button**

```
@IBAction func testBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    lineAnimation.duration = 5
    lineAnimation.fromValue = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height)
    lineAnimation.toValue = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    lineAnimation.autoreverses = true
    lineAnimation.repeatCount = 100
    animatedLineView.layer.add(lineAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

**This is what the view looks like *before* the button is pressed**

[image: Before button is pressed]

**This is what the view looks like *after* the button is pressed**

[image: After button is pressed]

**Why is the green view halving in size, and what can I do to prevent that?**

Comment: have you tried using `width: self.view.frame.width` in `animatedLineView.frame` setting up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the `position` of a layer is the center point, so when your animations starts it's moving the center of the green bar to the left edge, which is why it looks like it's cutting it in half.  Change your x value to the center of the bar and you will stop seeing that issue.  You will also need to adjust your y value to account for this being the center, and not the origin too.

Comment: @Joe In case you're curious, you can see details about that `position` property in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410791-position

Comment: Thanks. adjusting the anchorPoint of the green view was cleaner than compensating for the centerpoint within the actual animation.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (don't have time to check, and can't see the screenshots too) that it's not shrinking, it's moving aside and half hidden